# loading a UITableViewController from a selected indexpath in a UICollectionViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Im trying to get the `VC` that corresponds with the cell of the table view to load when tapped. I am trying to set the `indexPath` as the `selectedIndexPath` and set up the segue in the collection view, then use that in the tableView but it is throwing an error. Here is the code.

```
import UIKit

private let reuseIdentifier = "profileCell"


class CompanyCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

//MARK: - View Did Load

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .Plain, target: nil, action: nil)

}


// MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource

override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}


override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return stuff.company.count
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ProfileCollectionViewCell

    cell.profileImageView.image = UIImage(named: stuff.company[indexPath.row]["image"]!)

    return cell
}

//MARK: - Prepare For Segue

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "profileSegue" {
        let profileVC = segue.destinationViewController as!
            MyProfileTableViewController
        let cell = sender as! UICollectionViewCell
        let indexPath = collectionView?.indexPathForCell(cell)

        profileVC.selectedIndexPath = indexPath

    }
}
```

}

and then

```
import UIKit

class MyProfileTableViewController: UITableViewController {

//MARK: - View Did Load

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}





//MARK: - Table View Data Source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if let indexPath = selectedIndexPath {

        let row = stuff.company[indexPath.row]

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myProfileCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyProfileTableViewCell
            cell.heroImageView.image = UIImage(named: row["image"]!)
            title = row["name"]
            cell.nameLabel.text = row["name"]
            cell.statusLabel.text = row["description"]
            return cell

    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myProfileCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyProfileTableViewCell
        cell.heroImageView.image = UIImage(named: stuff.profile["profile image"]!)
        title = stuff.profile["name"]
        cell.nameLabel.text = stuff.profile["name"]
        cell.statusLabel.text = stuff.profile["status"]
        return cell
    }
}

//MARK: - Variables

var selectedIndexPath: NSIndexPath?
```

}

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'request for rect at invalid index path

Answer (score 0):

Ah I see, you are not checking if your collectionView?.indexPathForCell is returning a valid result.

```
   if let cell = sender as? UICollectionViewCell {
       // Cell is valid
       if let indexPath = collectionView?.indexPathForCell(cell) {
           // indexPath is valid
       } else {
           // indexPath is invalid
       }
   } else {
       // cell is invalid
   }
```

I suspect your indexPath from your table and your indexPath from your selection view are being mixed up, the code posted above should help you debug that.

Beyond that, I believe you can accomplish your intended result by:

1) Saving your selectedIndexPath in the didSelectCellAtIndexPath: method

2) Reading the selectedIndexPath in prepareForSegue instead of deriving the indexPath from the segue sender